# Concat a bunch of log.gz files in S3 into a CSV

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3

I get over 1000 log.gz files in and S3 bucket per hour, I'm trying to concat them all into one CSV and later load them to snowflake.

I continually get stuck "getting" the objects.

#attempt

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('some_bucket')
prefix = 'some_prefix'
df = pd.DataFrame()

#contents get corrupted when i add the date filter in the key
#but without that second filter, the file contents will print
file_list = [f for f in bucket.objects.all() if f.key[-3:] == '.gz' and '/20231114T06' in f.key]

# for file in file_list:
    # print(file.get()['Body'].read().decode(encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore"))

objs = []
for file in file_list:
    body = file.get()['Body'].read().decode(encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore")
    objs.append(body)    
    jsonObject = [json.loads(line) for line in objs.readlines()]
    df['data'] = jsonObject
    df = pd.json_normalize(df['data'])
```

The above returns `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'readlines'`. I don't know how to get/open/read the contents from inside the `file_list`. The `file_list` is a `<class 'list'>`.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: `body` is just a string, so you can just operate on it directly with something like `jsonObject = [json.loads(line) for line in body.split("\n") if line];`